# Operator does not exist: integer = character varying

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, mybatis

I'm losing my mind over an exception and I need your help.

I've written a query into a mapper that retrieves records from a table based on two conditions: "location" IN a list and "skill" in another one.

So, basically, if the user selects more than one skills to look for, the query recovers all the records with those skills...

So simple yet so twister because I'm using two foreach... one works and the other one doesn't...

This is the query:

```
<select id="selectAllByFilter" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
select distinct
<include refid="Base_Column_List" /><include refid="Join_Column_List" />
from "ANAG_REQS" A JOIN "ANAG_REQS_RISORSE" R ON A."ID_REQS_RDA"=R."ID_REQS" LEFT JOIN "SEC_USER" U ON R."ID_USER"=U."ID"
LEFT JOIN "USER_LOCATION" S ON S."ID_REQS_USER"= R."ID_REQS"
LEFT JOIN "USER_SKILL" RS ON RS."ID_REQS_USER"= R."ID_REQS"
LEFT JOIN "USER_CUSTOMER" RC ON RC."ID_REQS"= R."ID_REQS"
WHERE 1=1
<if test="filter.idREQS != null">
    AND A."ID_REQS_RDA" = #{filter.idREQS,jdbcType=INTEGER}
</if>
<if test="filter.states != null and filter.states.size()>0 and not statesuspended">
    AND A."state_RDA" IN 
    <foreach item="item" collection="filter.states" index="index"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">           
        #{item}
    </foreach>
    AND R."state" != 'suspended'
</if>
<if test="filter.states != null and filter.states.size()>0 and statesuspended">
    AND (A."state_RDA" IN 
    <foreach item="item" collection="filter.states" index="index"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">           
        #{item}
    </foreach>
    OR A."state_RDA" = 'published' AND R."state" = 'suspended')
</if>
<if test="filter.states.isEmpty() and statesuspended">
    AND A."state_RDA" = 'published' AND R."state" = 'suspended'
</if>
<if test="filter.dataREQSDa != null">
    AND A."DATA_REQS_RDA" &gt;= #{filter.dataREQSDa,jdbcType=DATE}
</if>
<if test="filter.dataREQSA != null">
    AND A."DATA_REQS_RDA" &lt;= #{filter.dataREQSA,jdbcType=DATE}
</if>
 <if test="filter.pm != null and filter.pm != ''">
    <bind name="pattern1" value="'%' + filter.pm + '%'" />
    AND lower(U."USER_NAME") LIKE lower(#{pattern1})
</if>
<if test="filter.CUSTOMER != null">     
    AND RC."ID_CUSTOMER" = #{filter.CUSTOMER,jdbcType=INTEGER}
</if>
<if test="filter.locationselected != null and filter.locationselected.size()>0">
    AND S."ID_LOCATION" IN 
    <foreach item="item" collection="filter.locationselected" index="index"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
          #{item}
    </foreach>
</if>
<if test="filter.skills != null and filter.skills.size()>0">
    AND RS."ID_SKILL" IN 
    <foreach item="item" collection="filter.skills" index="index"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
          #{item}
    </foreach>
</if>
</select>
```

The exception is being thrown on the latest foreach (filter.skills).

The problem is that the previous foreach (filter.locationSelected) works like a charm. The only difference is that skills is a list of Integers while locationSelected is a list of Strings. But this shouldn't be the cause because I've even tried using a list of String but the problem remains...

RS.ID_SKILL is an int4 so, as long as my logic goes (if I'm not going crazy) I'm basically checking if an int is in a list of integers............

But still I got a BadSQLGrammarException stating: **operator does not exist: integer = character varying Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.**

What am I doing wrong?!

Save me!

EDIT: S."ID_LOCATION" is, instead, a varchar so I'm checking if its content is in a list of string... Based on this the only logical conclusion is that mybatis' foreach doesn't work with list of integers..... I don't know.....

Comment: I'm pretty sure your XML is not what you think it is - hint: ">" closes a XML tag...

Comment: if you mean the </select> it was jsut a typo ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to modify the query by:
Replacing

```
AND RS."ID_SKILL" IN
```

by

```
AND cast(RS."ID_SKILL" as character varying) IN
```